# Different ways to fetch values from web services in react redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga, redux-thunk

Trying to find the best way to fetch values from web services in ReactJs, redux.

Found ways using useEffects, fetch, redux-thunk, redux-saga.

But which is best to be used..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad bad question. Okay, I cannot even explain why it's bad. I'll start with this, you're talking about completely different things.
I guess you're asking about how to make network requests in react. Here's brief description of the things you're talking about and why they are used:

**useEffect**: It's a hook in react, with which you can run an effect(basically running a function) on every or if depending on a state, some renders.

**fetch**: It is a web API with which you can make ajax requests(network requests) which is based on promises. Previously, we had XHR for doing so which is event-based. It is still used because fetch doesn't allow tracking the download progress of the response download. 'Should I use fetch or XHR for making requests', now that'd be a good question.

**redux-thunk && redux-saga**: Now you'd wanna use this with redux. In redux, as you probably know, dispatching action is synchronous. So if you wanna do some asynchronous task and dispatch the action object after that, then look into redux-thunk or redux-saga.

So the question shouldn't be 'Which of these should you use for fetching things off the web', because they're not specifically used for that purpose.

Comment: Okay thanks, I got it now. I am new to reactJs. So just wanted to know how to get values from an api(say an url returning Json responses). And then simply display the response on the component...

Comment: a standard way of doing so would be to use fetch or xhr(or take a look into axios, a very popular library for making network requests), inside useEffect of your component, and update state with result.

Comment: can you please check my question, no one able to help me on this as of now  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68504256/react-redux-action-dispatch-on-button-click-not-working/68504728?noredirect=1#comment121068686_68504728

Answer (score 0):

There are many differnt ways to doing that.
Basically useEffect is a hook and can not fetch any data directly.
Then you must pay attention to your app and select one that meet the needs of you. So there is no any best. If your application ia in a larg scale, i suggest react-query, then redux saga(if api reault is needed in some places)